# Navigation text interfering with regular?

Tags: html, css, text

I'm not sure what's going on here, but I'm trying to get it so the "Welcome to blabla" is on the right side of my thead. But it seems to glitch out?

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvZ9D.png

CSS Code:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0;
}

.content {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #B9B9B9;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #000;
}

#navBack {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgb(30,87,153);
    background: rgb(69,72,77);
    background: rgb(246,248,249);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-bottom: solid #424242;
}

#navBack ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

#navBack li {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
#navBack ul a {
    background-image: url(images/nav_sep.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
}

#navBack ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.copyright {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgb(246,248,249);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-top: solid #424242;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #000;
}

.copyright a {
    color: green;
}

#theadTitle {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgb(246,248,249);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: solid #424242;
}

#thead {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Noszscape - Home</title>
        <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="navBack">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="thead" style="width: 75%">
                <div id="theadTitle" > Welcome to Naszscape! </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <span style="font-style:italic"><strong>All rights reserved &copy;</span> <span style="color: skyblue"><a href="http://www.runelocus.com/forums/member.php?67852-317-Delta-Coder">317 Delta Coder</a></span> <span style="font-style:italic">2014</strong></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually you will have a better chance to get the answers you're looking for, and get them faster, by making your code short and to the point. Try removing any code that isn't directly involved in the part where your problem occurs, or try making a simplified analogous code that exhibits the same problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline style of `width: 75%` which is pushing the text off the side.

I would remove that and the `max-width: 1200px;` and add `text-align: right;` to the `#theadTitle` element.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zcg5v/)